# How to begin topology between two distinct shaped meshes

Tags: modeling

I have been using real items to help me learn modeling.

The following smoking pipe picture has a "bowl"-shape that blends smoothly into a diamond/rotated square for the mouth piece.

I have been searching tutorials for hours and trying to use what I've learned so far but having no luck coming close. I honestly don't know where to even start.

I can get the basic shapes, it's the "curved blend" between them where I'm severely lacking knowledge. I'm not sure what to search for, nothing I've found seems applicable.

Do I start with two meshes and somehow blend between them? Do I extrude vertices from the "bowl" to form the diamond base of the mouthpiece and somehow create some curved blends?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use *LoopTools > Bridge*?

Create a sphere with a subdivided and smoothed cube:

[image]

Cut off the top, extrude:

[image]

Cut off a hole:

[image]

Create plane, delete the face only, bevel its vertices:

[image]

Bridge the hole and the plane:

[image]

Make the shape fit with the pipe profile:

[image]

Add *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth:

[image]

File here: [image]

Comment: This looks great! I will try to walk through these steps, I hope I understand everything once I do. Can you share the blend file in case I need reference it?

Comment: sure, I've edited my answer

Comment: I was able to reproduce the pieces I was having trouble with! Thanks! Minor, but when you cut off the top and extruded, how did you get the vertices to be level? You'd be extruding the uneven edges/verts.

Comment: After cutting off the top, to level the top edge of vertices you need to select this top edge loop and scale them to zero along the Z axis. Keyboard shortcut for this operation is, with the top edge loop of vertices selected, hit the S key (to scale) Z key (to restrict scaling to Z axis) and 0 key (to scale to zero). S Z 0  and validate with LMB (Left Mouse Button).

Comment: It could be better but here's my own attempt https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/basic-untextured-smoking-pipe-e79bd24a88244433ab4d2997bdb69207

Comment: not bad, you need to move some vertices on the bottom